# Cascade of Downsample and Upsample

Tags: z-transform, multirate

Consider a cascade involving a downsampler (factor $M$) and an upsampler (factor $L$). For the sequence

$$x[n] \rightarrow  D \xrightarrow{{v_{1}[n]}} U \rightarrow y[n]$$

where $D$ denotes downsampling and $U$ denotes upsampling, we can write in frequency domain

$$V_{1}(z) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right)$$

$$Y_{1}(z) = V_{1}\left(z^{L}\right) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{L}{M}}W_{M}^{-Lk}\right)$$
where $W_M = e^{-j2\pi/M}$

For the sequence

$$x[n] \rightarrow U \xrightarrow{{v_{2}[n]}} D \rightarrow y_{2}[n]$$

we can write in frequency domain

$$V_{2}(z) = X(z^{L})$$

$$Y_{2}(z) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}V_{2}\left(z^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{L}{M}}W_{M}^{-Lk}\right)$$

Hence, $Y_{1} = Y_{2}.$ However, the cascade of downsampler and upsampler is not supposed to be commutative. What is the error in the above expressions?

Comment: A downsampler and upsampler are ***not*** commutative **unless** there is, in neither signal, any spectral content at frequencies equal to or above half of the sample rate of the output of the downsampler

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson polyphase rational resamplers nonwithstanding, though!

Comment: @MaxFrost there are two mistakes in your equations, please see my answer. Feel free to edit your question with the correct expressions, and I'll edit my answer to leave the answer part intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in you derivation of $Y_1(z)$ and $Y_2(z)$:

1. For $Y_1(z)$, just have a typo (it's $X$, not $V$):

$$Y_{1}(z) = V_{1}\left(z^{L}\right) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{L}{M}}W_{M}^{-Lk}\right)\tag{1}$$

2. For $Y_2(z)$: it's $W_M^{-k}$, not $W_M^{-Lk}$ (see **EDIT**), which gives:
   $$Y_{2}(z) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}V_{2}\left(z^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{L}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right)\tag{2}$$

Then, see [this tutorial](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/6798/1/VAIprocieee90.pdf) (Appendix A):

> $Y_1(z)$ and $Y_2(z)$ are identical except for the powers of $W$
> appearing in both. The right sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are identical if
> and only if the collection of $M$ numbers $W_M^{-Lk},\,\, 0 \leq k
> > \leq M-1$ is equal to the collection $W_M^{-k},\,\, 0 \leq k \leq
> > M-1$.

You can refer to the provided link for the derivation, but the end condition is:

> This in turn is true if and only if $M$ and $L$ are relatively prime (i.e., do not share a common factor greater than unity).

$M$ and $L$ are sometimes also referred to as [co-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) integers.

---

**EDIT**: explaining why $Y_2(z)$ depends on $W_M^{-k}$, not $W_M^{-kL}$

- In (1), we're **decimating, then expanding**: $$x[n] \rightarrow  D \xrightarrow{{v_{1}[n]}} U \rightarrow y[n]$$
  **Decimate**:
  $$V_1(z) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right)$$
  Define $z_1 = z^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}$ which simplifies the expression for $V_1(z)$ to:
  $$V_1(z) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z_1\right)$$
  **Expand**:
  $$Y_1(z) = V_1(z^L) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z_1^L\right) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{L}{M}}W_{M}^{-kL}\right)$$
- In (2), we're **expanding, then decimating**: $$x[n] \rightarrow U \xrightarrow{{v_{2}[n]}} D \rightarrow y_{2}[n]$$
  **Expand**:
  $$V_2(z) = X(z^L)$$
  Define $z_2 = z^L$, which gives $$V_2(z) = X(z_2)$$
  **Decimate**:

\begin{align}
Y_{2}(z) &= \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}V_2\left(z^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z_2^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left((z^L)^{\frac{1}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}X\left(z^{\frac{L}{M}}W_{M}^{-k}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Have made the correction in $Y_{1}(z)$. Thank you for pointing. For $Y_{2}(z)$, is there a reason why it's $W_{M}^{-k}$ and not $W_{M}^{-Lk}$?

Comment: @MaxFrost Edited my answer, hope that's enough detail ;)
If you’re satisfied please don’t forget to mark the answer accepted so that it doesn’t keep popping back up ;)